# Send raw bulk index query in NEST or serialize ONLY the document in a specific way

Tags: c#, serialization, elasticsearch, nest

I need to enable Objects TypeHandling for the JsonSerializer that is used for bulk index query. However, when I change the Serializer settings for NEST, the bulk query is being serialized wrong as a whole.

The serializer I used:

```
public class SearchJsonNetSerializer : JsonNetSerializer
{
    public SearchJsonNetSerializer(IConnectionSettingsValues settings)
        : base(settings)
    {
    }

    protected override void ModifyJsonSerializerSettings(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
        settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
    }
}
```

The output I got:

```
{"index":{"$type":"Nest.BulkIndexOperation`1[[TestProject.TestDTO, TestProject]], Nest","_type":"testdto","_id":"146949756709543936"}}
{"$type":"TestProject.TestDTO, TestProject","Id":146949756709543936,"Title":"test","TitleRaw":"test"}
```

The second line is correct, however, NEST used the serializer settings to serialize the initial line in a way that totally destroys the request.

Is there a way to apply the changed serializing only to the actual object? If not, is there a way to send a raw, prepared json string as a request for a bulk query? I've seen that functionality in older version, but in the current one - 2.0, I just can't find a way to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1155

Sadly you can not do the following in `JSON.NET`

```
[JsonObject(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects)]
public class MyPoco {}
```

That would solve the issue at hand, only enabling that typenamehandling for your specific types. Sadly it can only be specified on properties. Would make a great feature request there.

You have two options either writing a custom serializer for your type, or preserialize them and send them using the lowlevel client, but then you need to add the metadata items manually as well.

```
var client = new ElasticClient().LowLevel.Bulk<BulkResponse>("index", "type", new[]
{
    "",
});
```

NEST does provide several ways to get true covariant search results without having to index `$type`:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/covariant-search-results.html

Comment: Bummer :( I wanted to abstain from using the low level client, as this was my previous approach, which I wanted to replace with NEST client. Well, I guess the low level client usage stays.

Comment: @Slowacki Is there a particular reason that you need the `type` information? Perhaps the problem can be solved with a different solution?

Comment: I'm using several DTO classes that implement the same interface. With TypeNameHandling.Objects set on indexation, on search the hits in ElasticsearchResponse are already mapped back to their correct DTO classes.

Comment: @Slowacki have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/covariant-search-results.html on other ways how to solve this without introducing `$type`

Comment: @MartijnLaarman Thanks! I've been refactoring my search and used this approach now. Works like a charm!